# Angular: Sticky things on table header

Tags: css, angular, sticky, tableheader

I am working on a medium-sized project where we need to display some information in a complex table. The headers need to be **sticky**, so that when you scroll down the page, the header sticks to the top of the table.

As I want to support IE and earlier versions of Chrome, I *DO NOT* want to be using the `position: sticky;`. I do not mind it involving a bit of JS, as my previous attempts for this has also included that.

I've already gone the way, of simply making doing this by JS and making the `position: fixed;` when the user scrolled further down that the table header. Yet also this seems to have the same trouble as illustrated in the stackblitz further down. 
This makes me consider that it might have something with the sizing I'm not getting right.

I've looked a bit into the using of [Angular Sticky Things](https://github.com/w11k/angular-sticky-things/). I just can wrap my head around how to use this library in the given context:

I have a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7mhs3) with example usage of this.

I would love if someone could give me a hint as to how on earth, this should be made.

I expect that the whole `thead` moves down, without scaling itself or scaling the rest of the table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the first CSS line with `display:inherit` to get closer to what you would want... `width` property is for matching the width between the sticky header and the rest of the table...

```
thead.is-sticky{display:inherit;width:calc(100vw - 35px)!important;}
```

The only limitation which remains is the limitation of the table. For e.g. if the heading is too big it messes up the look on smaller screens, so we break the word, hence this second CSS line:

```
th, tr{word-break: break-word;}
```

I forked your [stackblitz with these changes here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpshkk)